# How do I place fragments to the default root ViewGroup of an Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

According to the android developer guide,

> To get started, your layout must include a ViewGroup in which you
>   place each Fragment associated with a tab. Be sure the ViewGroup has a
>   resource ID so you can reference it from your tab-swapping code.
>   Alternatively, if the tab content will fill the activity layout
>   (excluding the action bar), then your activity doesn't need a layout
>   at all (you don't even need to call setContentView()). Instead, you
>   can place each fragment in the default root ViewGroup, which you can
>   refer to with the android.R.id.content ID (you can see this ID used in
>   the sample code below, during fragment transactions).

But without the `setContentView()`, whenever I call `getActionBar()`, it returns null. I am wondering how would I place fragment in the `default root ViewGroup`? Do I add it through XML or programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But without the setContentView(), whenever I call getActionBar(), it
>   returns null

On what Android versions did you test that? If I remember right this do happens on the 11 and 12 API levels but on other versions it works.

To avoid complication you should just set the content view to a layout with a simple `FrameLayout` and use that as the container for your fragments. You could also try just using [`Window.FLAG_ACTION_BAR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) without a content view:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your fragment to default viewgroup which has id `android.R.id.content`. You don't need to layout your activity using `setContentView()` to do this.

```
mFragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
```